# Javascript: got 'undefined' when using 'this' to access outer scope variable in 'private' child function

Tags: javascript, this, scope

I have a habit of setting all my variables to its parent scope, instead of calling them implicitly:

```
function outer() {
    var x, y;
    function inner() {
        var x = this.x;
        x = ...// doing stuff here
        y = ....// implicit calling parent variable
    }
}
```

so that if I mistype my variable, it won't go to global space. But it seems like declare variable with `this` within private function will return me `undefined`:

```
function f() {
    var x = [0];
    function f1() { 
        console.log('f1:', this.x, x); 
        f2(); 
    }
    function f2() { 
        console.log('f2:', this.x, x); 
    }
    return { x:x , f1:f1 };
}

var foo = f();    
foo.f1();
    //output
    f1: [0] [0]
    f2: undefined [0]
```

If I understand it correctly, it shouldn't happen, as both `f1` and `f2` should have access to its outer scope by using `this`. Is there any concept I am missing here? Or is it something I just have to live with for now?

Update: To clarify, my main concern is why there is the difference between `f1` and `f2`. I prefer to keep `f2` hidden because it will do some internal works, and other developers should not use it when they declare something from `f()`.

Comment: `this` in `f2` is `f1`, not `outer`

Comment: `this` is the context of execution for the function — not the function's inner scope. When you call `foo.f1()` then inside `f1()` `this` refers to `foo`. If you want to use variables from parent scope in the inner function, just reference them by name — without `this`.

Comment: You should give this book a try: http://www.packtpub.com/object-oriented-javascript/book.

Comment: You forgot to add `var x = this.x;` inside your `f1` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also try this:

```
function f() {
    var x = [0];
    function f1() { 
        console.log('f1:', this.x, x); 
        f2.call(this); 
    }
    function f2() { 
        console.log('f2:', this.x, x); 
    }
    return { x:x , f1:f1 };
}

var foo = f();    
foo.f1();
```

This way the context of f2 will be properly set.

In your code `this` in f2 refers to the window object, because f2 wasn't declared as a method. f1 was declared as a method of the returned object when writing `{ x:x , f1:f1 }`. In f2 x is visible not because it is run in the scope of f() but because f2 gets it as a closure. That means in f2, all variables will be visible that was in the same scope when it was created.

What the `this` refers to will be set at invocation time. If you run a function  as property of an object like `foo.f1()` it is considered as a method, and `this` will be set to the object. But when you just invoke a function like `f2()` the scope will be the same it was invoked in, in your case it is the window object, because foo is a global in the window object.

In f1 this refers to the hidden f(), therefore if you want f2 also be run in that scope you can use `f2.call(this)`. The argument of .call() will be the `this` of the function when run.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and thank you very much for a clear and throughout explanation. I will mark this as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

When your `f` function returns an object, it doesn't have `f2` method. `f2` method is an inner method of `f` and exists only in its scope.

If you use this code:

```
function f() {
    var x = [0];
    function f1() { 

        console.log('f1:', this.x, x); 
        this.f2(); 
    }
    function f2() { 
        console.log('f2:', this.x, x); 
    }
    return { x:x , f1:f1, f2:f2};
}

var foo = f();    
foo.f1();
```

then `this` in `f1` method will have access to the `f2` method of `this`, and object's `f2` method will return the correct `x`.

Comment: I would like to keep `f2` hidden so people won't accidentally use it. Solution from @Sylvanus solves my problem. However, your comment right below my question seems reasonable to me. So I follow it and put some test to confirm my understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/PbPbz/
I put a variable `a` in `f1`, so now if `this` in `f2` refer to `f1`, then I should be able see it in `f2`. But it seems not the case.

Comment: In that fiddle the this in f2 refers to the window object, because f2 wasn't declared as a method. f1 was declared as a method of the returned object when writing { x:x , f1:f1 }

Comment: In f2 x is visible not because it is run in the scope of f() but because f2 gets it as a closure. That means in f2, all variables will be visible that was in the same scope when it was created.

Answer (score 0):

You returned this from the function:

```
{ x : x, f1 : f1 }
```

This sets the the `this` objects properties to the above. `f2` is not apart of the object so it can't access the `this` that it refers to.